# Updating Subsequent Array Elements with Value from 1st Element in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am working in a Mongo 3.2 environment. I have a situation where I currently have a value for a property called "customerNumber" in the first element of a property called "membership", which is an array. This "membership" property sits at the root of the document. So this relevant part of my document looks something like this:

```
membership: [
 {
   _id: 'abc123',
   anotherProp: <value>,
   customerNumber: 123
 },
   _id: 'def456',
   anotherProp: <value>
 },
]
```

And this is true for all documents in the collection. Now, for one document it would be relatively simple to update every subsequent element in the array with the same property and value found in the first element. But I'm wondering if there's a Mongo way to accomplish this for all documents in the collection?

In other words, based on the instance above, I would want the document to look like this when the update's been done:

```
membership: [
 {
   _id: 'abc123',
   anotherProp: <value>,
   customerNumber: 123
 },
   _id: 'def456',
   anotherProp: <value>,
   customerNumber: 123
 },
]
```

UPDATE: Based on a suggestion, I tried this:

```
db.customers.update(
   { membership: { $elemMatch: { customerNumber: { $exists: false } } } },
   { $set: { "membership.$.customerNumber" : "$membership.0.customerNumber" } },
)
```

... but this doesn't work, and produces the rather obtuse error message:

> The selection is invalid and cannot be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on mongodb [$ (update)](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/) and [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists)

```
db.<collection_name>.update(
   { membership: { $elemMatch: { customerNumber: { $exists: false } } } },
   { $set: { "membership.$.customerNumber" : '123' } },
)
```

Comment: yes, `collection name` and you can add `{ anotherProp: { $exists: false } }` for more matches.

Comment: To clarify, I won't know the actual value to be assigned, as it will be different for each document. I need Mongo to look up the value for customerNumber in the first element of the array for any particular document, and update all subsequent array elements with that same value on that particular document. Then it needs to move on to the next document and do the same thing, etc. So maybe using `$membership.0.customerNumber` would work?

Comment: `{ $set: { "membership.$.customerNumber" : "$membership.0.customerNumber" } }`

Comment: No, it didn't. See my edited question (above) with an update on this. I have the code I tried there, as well as the error message I got.